# How to integrate a vuejs template library into a Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to implement an admin panel for the site. I decided to use something popular. Since I'm doing it on Laravel, then the choice fell on something on Vue. I chose [vue-element-admin](https://github.com/PanJiaChen/vue-element-admin), top star on github stars. Along the way, superficially familiarized with vue, vue-cli, npm and other things that apply there. This "template" (vue-element-admin), or more correctly already called a "library", even has documentation, everything is fine.

But I just got stuck at the integration stage of laravel and vue-element-admin: where to unpack this library? Where to start then npm? How to tell laravel about her? I wanted to make the administrative part of the site as SPA, and the user part in the classic version

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow,

If you want to start with npm you can navigate to the laravel project folder and run `npm install`

In terms of implementing the library you can do so in this file:
`resources/js/app.js`

There are also other resources on how to get started with Laravel + Vue. If you are using Laravel for the first time you should check out https://laracasts.com they cover lots of topics about Laravel and general Web Development.

A couple web articles regarding your question: https://medium.com/@damijolayemi/workflow-tip-how-to-use-vuejs-in-a-laravel-package-71fef6ea1d12 & [Import vue package in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925886/import-vue-package-in-laravel)